# Swift (4) - can a generic function be specialized over types whose init() produces an "empty" object?

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to constrain a generic function to only types whose init() produces an empty object? For instance:

```
public func constructDefaultObject<C>() -> C where C: SomeProtocol {
    return C()
}
```

without a `where` clause, this produces the error:

```
error: numbers.playground:3:12: error: non-nominal type 'C' does not support explicit initialization
    return C()
           ^~~
```

and a similar error if I use `C.init()` instead:

```
error: numbers.playground:3:12: error: type 'C' has no member 'init'
    return C.init()
           ^ ~~~~
```

There seem to be some protocols that provide a no-arg `init` - for instance, `RangeReplaceableCollection` and `SetAlgebra` both have inits that produce empty collections. But there doesn't seem to be a protocol that encompasses the notion of "the no-arg constructor creates an empty instance of a collection" for all collection types.

Comment: @BrainHeim What's your definition of the `HasDefaultConstructor` protocol?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? There's a good reason why a protocol representing "*any* type that can be initialised with `init()`" doesn't exist in the standard library; it doesn't express any meaningful semantics about the instance constructed. I would highly recommend having a good read of https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/

Comment: @Alexander I think the semantic I'm after here is more or less what would be considered the identity element in a commutative monoid. For collections that would be an empty collection, for numerical types it would be zero. That is a bit more specialized that just "DefaultConstructible", and I should have mentioned that in my question. I'll update.

Comment: @Hamish - thanks! That article is very helpful. I'm coming from C++, where std::is_constructible<C>::value would provide the TMP solution. But of course, templates and protocols are different beasts.

Comment: @Hamish I just read through that article, thanks again for sharing. As to what I'm trying to achieve, I have a function that starts with an empty `C`, and then passes off element-adding functionality to a handler. This handler is called multiple times in an inner loop, and needs to be customizable, so I couldn't just pass in a prebuilt collection or a few extra parameters. So in this case I do really just need a protocol that expresses `EmptyConstructible`, and nothing else – not even `insert`, `append`, etc. But this is kind of a corner case, so it doesn't bother me if the answer is no.

Comment: @BrianHeim I understand what you're looking for, I'm asking you about what actual code you wrote to define `HasDefaultConstructor`

Comment: @Alexander oh oh sorry! well, that's the point of the question – I'm asking whether that exists in some form in the standard library, or can be approximated with some other approach.

Comment: @BrianHeim Oh, well if that's your question, then yes, yes that *can* be done

Comment: @BrianHeim Why don't you bundle the full behaviour of this object into the protocol? The default initializer, `insert`, `append`, and everything else this handler of yours could do with one of these objects

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, but it's not of much use:

```
// This is a shitty protocol that doesn't do much. Don't use it.
public protocol DefaultConstructible { 
    init()
}

public func constructDefaultObject<C>() -> C where C: DefaultConstructible {
    return C()
}
```

Comment: I think this answers the original question, but not the one I had after it was revised and discussed in the comments. Thanks for the thoughts though, this has been very helpful. :)

Comment: @BrianHeim In that case, open a new question. Moving the goal posts like this makes the comments/answers desynchronized and confusing

Comment: Thanks for you efforts @Alexander, you answer helped me figure out my problem.